# Xml or Local Storage for saving forms?

Tags: xml, html, xslt

I'm in the process of creating a mobile hybrid app with html5. The main purpose of the app is to fill out forms, save as a draft (where it can be edited) when offline and then send to the mysql database when there's a connection available. Keep in mind, the forms a quite complex, with images and signatures etc.

My question is what will be the best way to save the forms and send to database. Should I use xml and xslt to save the data or should i use local storage. I really need some suggestions as to which will be the better way to do this as i'm really new to web dev, let alone mobile app dev. I appreciate all the help.

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1):

I think your question is a little bit confusing. XML is a data format and local storage is where the data can be stored.

Since your app will also be used offline, you should use local storage to store the data. The format of your data can be [XML](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_whatis.asp), [JSON](http://json.org/), etc. I recommend you to use JSON coz it's much more lightweight and less verbose compared to XML.

I hope this answer your question somehow. Cheer!